# Can my familiar use the additional action from the Haste spell to attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, actions

The *haste* spell (p. 250 of the *Player's Handbook*) grants an extra action that can only be used to take one of a limited set of action.  One of those options is the Attack action.

If I cast the *haste* spell on my familiar, which normally can't use its action to attack, can it use this special action from *haste* to attack?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### No - it's still an attack

Per the [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) spell description:

> Your familiar acts independently of you, but it always obeys your commands. In combat, it rolls its own initiative and acts on its own turn. **A familiar can't attack**, but it can take other actions as normal.

If it cannot attack as its first action, it cannot attack on a haste-induced action.

Now, familiars of warlocks with the [Pact of the Chain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#PactBoon-389) feature are allowed to attack:

> when **you take the Attack action**, you can forgo one of your own attacks to allow your familiar to use its reaction to make one attack of its own.

But even if you were hasted and got two attacks per round, the familiar would still only get one attack, as it only has one reaction per round.

Comment: I never liked how the spell says it can take "other actions" when it didn't actually exclude any *actions* but instead excluded something much larger than just the Attack action

Comment: @Medix2 Good point, but I'm curious: How would you have phrased it? I've tried, but it's hard to come up with something that still reads like a decent sentence.